# How to find the x and y coordinates of a given value using Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, coordinates

To make a board game using a 2D numpy array, user to input a number and I need X & Y value of that number being returned in separate variables.

This is how I'd set up the array

```
board = np.array(["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08",
                      "09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16",
                      "17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24",
                      "25","26","  ","@@","29","30","31","32",
                      "33","34","35","@@","  ","38","39","40",
                      "41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48",
                      "49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56",
                      "57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64"])
board = board.reshape(8,8)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be done in many ways. One of it could be as follows:

```
value = input("Enter the board value")  # This allows the user to enter the value

found = np.squeeze(np.where(value == board))  # This numpy function finds where the array is equal to the board value

if found.size > 0:  # checks if the found value is not empty
    print('The value is present in the board at {}, {}'.format(found[0], found[1]))
else:
    print('Enter a valid input')
```

Comment: @WilliamKavanagh Glad to know. However, it would throw an unclear result for a double occurence of the @@. If you want that as a special purpose case, you can add it as else if (in python: elif) case. Do you want me to take care of that? or you want to take it as a learning process and figure that out yourself. I'd suggest the later ;)

Comment: Due to the nature of the array I know it wont throw a double array but thank you for the offer. Im taking it as a learning experience anyway because I feel im going to be using numpy alot

Comment: in this code something would have to go very wrong for a double occurence but thank you for the offer. I think il take it as a learning experience for now. Dont wanna become to reliant on this website